# c# totalseconds to equal 5 seconds with IF statement

Tags: c#

I want an IF statement that if 5 seconds has passed by then execute the block of chain. So far I got this code below but its not 5 seconds. How do I set it to 5 seconds.

```
DateTime myTIMER = DateTime.Today;
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(myTIMER).TotalSeconds >= 5)
{ execute some code}
```

The problem is TotalSeconds does not equal to 5 seconds. Do I have to put 5000 in order for it to be 5 seconds or 500?

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. `myTIMER` will contain the current date with the time zeroed so, effectively, the time at midnight of the morning of the current day. You then compare that to the current date AND time, so the result will ALWAYS be `true` if you execute it 5 seconds after midnight or later. You should almost certainly be using `DateTime.Now` rather than `DateTime.Today`. If you then compare that to `DateTime.Now` immediately then of course it will be `false` because 5 seconds can't have passed. You have to actually let 5 seconds pass.

Comment: Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you think an `If` statement is the right way to achieve it?

Comment: Yeah I agree with @John

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// ... more code

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

// ... long running code

stopwatch.Stop();

if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 5000)
{
    // 5 seconds or more
}
else
{
    // Less than 5 seconds
}
```

Upon re-reading the question, I realize it's not very clear and you may be looking for `Task.Delay()`. If so:

```
    // ... Some code
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

    // Now wait for 5 seconds before continuing
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    // 5 seconds have passed
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: @Human Benchmark Hope this answers your question